# PHP - Opening a File or Die on Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, fopen, fwrite

**Firstly**, this is probably considered a duplicate, BUT I've searched a lot on those other posts and none of them seem to work for me.

I am running Apache 2 on my Raspberry Pi as well as PHP 5.4.45

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('AvailableTickets.txt', 'w') or die('Failed to open file');
fwrite($fh, 'Test');
fclose($fh);
?>
```

I get `Failed to open file` when I run this code. This `AvailableTickets.txt` file exists within the same directory as this `test.php` file. I've tried adding a `./` before the file name, as well as `../www/`.

Still, when I access this file in my browser, the text file doesn't change.

Comment: Are the permissions on the text file correct that the apache or www-data user is able to view and write?

Comment: add `echo getcwd();` to see what the current directory is.  Then `echo file_exists(..)` to see if really is there, and finally try `echo is_readable(..)` to see if it's a permissions issue.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia I've tried all three and it passed. `echo getcwd();` returns  `/var/www` and `echo file_exists();` returns 1, as well as `echo is_readable();`. So I am more confused now on why it won't write.

Comment: oh for writing! try `echo is_writable();`

Comment: remove the `or die` part, and add these to the top
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
`ini_set('display_errors','1');`

Comment: @pcnate FileZilla says `-rw-r--r--`, whatever that means.

Comment: @GShocked that means file owner can read and write, file group can read, and everybody else can read. Who is the file owner?

Comment: @ThinkingMedia Doing that returns: 
`Warning: fopen(AvailableTickets.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/test.php on line 4

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/test.php on line 5

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/test.php on line 6`

Comment: @pcnate I'd assume that'd be the system (root) or pi (sudo user)? I'm not quite sure what's being asked.

Comment: You're trying to write `'w'` a file having no permissions: -rw-r--r--

Comment: @Axalix So how would I provide permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give PHP write permissions to the file

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/AvailableTickets.txt
chmod 644 /var/www/AvailableTickets.txt
```

Comment: @ThinkingMedia That's smart :)

Comment: @ThinkingMedia 644 doesn't work, but I figured out how to use this and 646 worked (Which sets public to read/write)

Comment: That's one way of doing it. I thought there was another way where you could grant permissions using the apache config or the `.htaccess` file, but I can't remember how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem.  Had the fopen in a function.  Would not produce the file in the same directory.  did all the pi:pi's and 777's, still no file.

About to throw the whole thing out when I thought of the optimizer.  So moved the fopen(fptr, " filename"); and fprintf header into the main init routine out of a function and it worked!

Apparantly the optimizer decided it wasn't needed!!

Optimizers cause no end of mysterious problems for tiny gain.
You don't need an optimizer you need a faster processor!

John